# COM not found fatal error

Tags: php, error-handling, com, fatal-error

I stumbled across an error which is

[image]

I added `extension=php_com_dotnet.dll` into `php.ini`, but the problem still occurs.

What can I do in this situation?

Comment: Do you updated right php.ini (PHP-CLI and PHP-FPM/mod_php have separated php.ini files)? Did you check if loaded (via `phpinfo`) ?

Comment: I updated it right in the folder where `php.exe` is in the root folder of whole php

Comment: can you show what you get from `<?php echo phpinfo() ?>`?

Comment: I have recently updated php to 7, xdebug and xampp